# What is the name of the area formed by two intersecting circles?

Tags: geometry, terminology

When two circles intersect they form an area which is "ellipse-like" in shape.  What is the name of this shape?

Comment: [Vesica piscis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vesica_piscis) and/or **mandorla**.

Answer (score 6):

The technical term is [lens.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lens_%28geometry%29)${}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score -1):

It's called a Vesica Piscis, which is Latin for "fish bladder," a reference to the shape of a fish's swim bladders.

Furthermore, for art history buffs, in Italian it is called a Mandorla, which is also the name used for it in art. Mandorlas were used in medieval and renaissance art as a frame for Christ and other heavenly figures, thought of as the shape of the gate to the Kingdom of Heaven.